# Product designers made a mistake, it is already in a released version, is it a defect?

Tags: development-process

From the QA-ops perspective:

product designers, product owners and this kind of people are often very "soft" with product requirements. They often put a lot of prio on function requirements but not on non-functional requirements.

There are some UX lacks when things doesn´t happen as desired. Developers did the job, they stick to the mocks to deliver incrementals ASAP.

I wouldn't call bugs, because it has something related with UX and then they must do something about as well. In the other hand, defects are considered on testing stage so,

**is it a defect?**

add your thought if needed: how would you call them? (I would call it defect as well but the definition sticks to testing)

Comment: What's your purpose in labelling it a defect or not? Really it's just another change that's needed, and should be prioritised like any other.

Answer (score 2):

The standard definitions of the term "defect" tend to refer to "imperfections or deficiencies in work products". Even if the developers implemented exactly what they were asked to create or what was laid out in a requirement or design or mockup, there could have been a defect in that requirement or design or mockup. The defect in the requirement or design propagated into the system.